# customize shipping method magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to change the view of shipping method in checkout page, this is what I have now:

[image]

I want to remove radio button and show free shipping if its free, otherwise I want to show flat rate, its decided by the total purchase amount.

But I am not able to find the page where I can change this. I found some files related to shipping:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
```

but shipping method content is not coming from these files.

Comment: How to remove the entire shipping, if it is free shipping i dont want to show the shipping rates method tab. how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The available methods are rendered in `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`

Look around line 34:

```
foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates):
```

You can add your condition below that line to show free shipping or flat rate.

**Edit:**
Alternatively, you can override `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available::getShippingRates()` method so that shipping method of your choice is displayed.

Comment: How to remove the entire shipping, if it is free shipping i dont want to show the shipping rates method tab. how can i do that?